# How can I know login success by using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to **scrape** website of stock company to get stock name and count that user had.

below is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

url = "https://www.mynamuh.com/tx/login/login.action"
data = {'userid':'ryulstor', "passwd_e2e_1_pwd__":"liams09", "ca_gb" :"Y"}

s = requests.Session()

with requests.Session() as s:
    login_page = s.get(url)
    html = login_page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    login_req = s.post(url, data= data)
    print(login_req.status_code)
```

Whether user id and password are correct or not, status_code return 200.
so I can't know login success. could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

So bs4 has a find function. So if you know what html pops up when you enter your id correctly, you can see if bs4 can find that html and if not you know you entered it wrong. I recommend you look at Beautiful Soup's documentary or watch sentdex's videos to find more about this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIPqt-OdmS0