# how to scrap email from https://www.facebook.com/business_page_name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the email. When I scrape the entire page I see everything but email.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
URL = "https://www.facebook.com/JewelleryByZM"
r = requests.get(URL)
  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Thats because you are not getting that page, you are getting a javascript block. Try logging in first then scraping.

Comment: even if I logged in how will the BeautifulSoup Know I am logged in, the url doesn't change @AaronCloud

Comment: You would need to login thru requests first, then navigate to the link then scrap the page.

Comment: @Let'sbecool I recommend you to checkout [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504135/how-can-i-know-login-success-by-using-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Or if that doesn't work, (because facebook hate scrapers and will try to stop you) You could use something like selenium and run a path to your current user on whatever browser you are using (this will use the cookies that fb gives you) and then scrape by web element. Thats what I would do and I think it would be easier to implement.

Comment: Another option would be to use another platform than Facebook, for e.g this specific business has a page on Twitter and Twitter has an API you can use https://developer.twitter.com.